# Can anybody explain the progress bar in "Review Important Org Changes"?

Tags: setup, release, critical-update, summer20

Since Summer'20 the following beta feature is available: Review Important Org Changes with Release Updates

I am trying to understand how I can use this effectively, but so far it's beyond me. Both the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release_updates.htm&type=5) and the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_cruc_changes.htm) are vague, to say the least.

Both say:

> Start or stop a test run, and view step update history by clicking Get
> Started

Well, I clicked Get Started on a number of critical updates. It activates the update in the sandbox in which I am doing this, but other than that... I have run Apex tests, did some other work in the sandbox. But the progress bar won't move.

Who can explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not automated. It's essentially a manual task checklist you can use to confirm which critical updates you've looked at or what steps you've done (steps provided by Salesforce).

Your progress bar will update as you check off items in the checklist

If you click on "Get Started" on a given update, you'll see a list of items to complete below the "test run" piece. Each update has its own amount. For those with more than one, you can click on each step to expand the text and "Complete" them.

[image]

After manually clicking "Mark as complete", the progress bar changes based on the # of steps completed (ex. 1 out of 4)

[image]

---

For those that just have one step (basically "Assess the impact of this release update"), you just click on "done".

[image]

It'll prompt again for "confirmation".

[image]

Once you do that, the progress bar turns green and shows 100%

[image]

Comment: Ah, what I missed was, I had to click on the arrow to the left of "Enable the critical update in a sandbox." Though for the two updates that I was looking at, there is only the section labeled "Assess the impact of this release update". After clicking that, a button is revealed labeled "Done". Click that and a popup appears with checkboxes. Do that and the progress bar is updated. The crucial step is to open up a section, I had missed that subtlety.